# How to compare the value of enumeration in JAVA

Tags: java, enumeration

I wanted to create something when the user login, if the login as User then it go into the first module else if the user login as admin it goes into the second module. The question is I have no idea on how to compare the user role by using enum.

```
for(int i = 0; i < staffCount; i++) {
    if(username.equals(staff[i].GetStaffID()) && pass.equals(staff[i].GetPassword()) && staff[i].GetUserRole().equals("User")){
        System.out.println("hello user");
    }
}
```

Here is my enum declaration in Staff class

```
enum userRole{
    Admin,
    User
}
```

Here is the setter and getter

```
public void SetUserRole(userRole userRole){
    this.userRole = userRole;
}

public userRole GetUserRole(){
    return userRole;
}
```

Comment: good to read: [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Enum values can be compared by `==` as the value is a global singleton object. And really do `enum UserRole` / `getUserRole`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
staff[i].GetUserRole().equals("User")
```

You probably mean

```
staff[i].GetUserRole().equals(userRole.User)
```

or

```
staff[i].GetUserRole() == userRole.User
```

As a side note, according to Java's naming conventions, the enum should really be named `UserRole`, and its values `ADMIN` and `USER`. Like this:

```
enum UserRole {
    ADMIN,
    USER
};
```

Answer (score 2):

replace `staff[i].GetUserRole().equals("User")`

with `staff[i].GetUserRole() == userRole.User`

because they refer to the same instance you can use == instead of `.equals`

also like Feredrico klez Culloca said, you should look into naming convention, constants like enum names tend to be in all caps, enums and classes and interfaces tend to be capitalized, and variable names and methods tend to be camelcase.